# Restful way of sending Pre-Post or Pre-Put warning message

Tags: java, rest, jersey, system-design

I am trying to convert a legacy application to Restful web-services. One of our old form displayed a warning message immediately on form load. This warning message depends on a user property.

For example, if there is a property **isInactiveByDefault** which when set to "true" will set the status of the newly created employee via `POST v1/employees` to "Inactive". User on "Employee" form load will see a warning message "Any new employee created will have inactive status".

I originally thought of providing a resource to get the status of the property and let the client handle whether to display the warning message or not based on the value of the property. But my manager wants to avoid any business logic in client side. As per him, this is a business logic and should be handled from server.

I am wondering what's the Restful way of sending this warning message. I could send the message with POST response but this would mean they will receive the message after the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that delegating the choice to display or not the message to the client is at the very frontier of what one may call "business logic". I believe there is room for debate here..

But let aside this point, and if we consider the message(s) to display as data then as soon as your client can make **REST** calls (via JS, AJAX or whatever), you should be able to query the server before or while the form loads (and wait/sync on that).

So it is perfectly fine and "RESTful" to perform a `GET` request on the service to i.e. retrieve a list of warning messages (eventually internationalized) and display them. The server will prepare this list of warnings based on such or such property and return it (as JSON or whatever). Your client will only have to display the parsed result of the request (0-N messages to list) next to your form.

**EDIT**

Example REST service for your use case:

```
@POST
@Path("/v1/employees")
public Response someFormHandlingMethod() {
   // Your form processing
   ...
   if(EmployeeParameters.isInactiveByDefault()) {
      emp.setInactive(true);
   }
   ...
}

@GET
@Path("/v1/employees/formwarnings")
public Response getEmployeeFormWarnings() {
   // "Business logic" -> Determine warning messages to return to client
   ...
   if(EmployeeParameters.isInactiveByDefault()) {
      warnings.add("Any new employee created will have inactive status");
   }
   ...
   // and return them in Response (entity as JSON or whatever). Could also be List<String> for example.
}
```

It is just an example so that you get the idea but the actual implementation will depend on your Jersey configuration, mappers/converters, annotations (such as `@Produces`), etc.

Comment: This is a good point. So when client calls GET v1/employees/{empid}, server also returns the warning in a custom header and client will read the warning from the header and display without having to deal with the content of the header. But this brings another issue that the GET /v1/employees/{empid} can be called from multiple other forms unrelated to creating an employee.

Comment: Hi, I'm not speaking about headers. More generally you should never add data into headers. I mean that the result of the GET request may be some data formatted as JSON and such data can be a list (a document with an array) of warning messages. I will update my answer to be more precise.  Concerning your second remark, its worth to say that it is applicable to any REST endpoint or method. As soon as you don't implement authorization and/or access controls, every REST endpoint can be called by any client code or form.

Answer (score 0):

The focus of a REST architecture is on the decoupling of clients from servers by defining a set of constraints both parties should adhere to. If those constraints are followed stringent it allows servers to evolve freely in future without having to risk breaking clients that also adhere to the REST architecture while such clients will get more robust toward change as a consequence. As such, a server should teach clients on how certain things need to look like (i.e. through providing forms and form-controls) and what further actions (i.e. links) the client can perform from the current state it is in.

By asking for `Pre-Post` or `Pre-Put` operations I guess you already assume an HTTP interaction, which is quite common for so called "RESTful" systems. Though as [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s) pointed out, HTTP is just a transport protocol whose application domain is the transfer of a document from a source to a target and any business rules we conclude from that interaction are just a side effect of the actual document management. So we have to come up with ways to trigger certain business activities based on the processing of certain documents. In addition to that, HTTP does not know anything like pre-post or pre-put or the like.

Usually a rule of thumb in distributed computing is to never trust any client input and thus validate the input on the server side again. The first validation solution worked on the server providing a client with a [Web form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) that teaches clients on the available properties of a resource as well as gave clients a set of input controls to interact with that form (i.e. a send button that upon clicking will marshal the input data to a representation format that is sent with a HTTP operation the server supports). A client therefore did not need to know any internals of the server as it was served with all the information it needed to make up the next request. This is in essence what HATEOAS is all about. Once a server received a request on a certain endpoint it started to process the received document, i.e. the input data, and if certain constraints it put on that resource were violated it basically sent the same form as before to the client, though this time with the input data of the client included and further markup that was added to the form representation that indicates the input error. Through style attributes added to that errors these usually stood out from the general page design notably (usually red text and/or box next to the input control producing the violation) and thus allowed for easier processing of the problems.

With the introduction of JavaScript some clever people came up with a way to not only send the form to the client, but also a script that automatically checks the user input in the background and if violated adds the above mentioned failure markup dynamically to the DOM of the current form/page and so inform a user on possible problems with the current input. This however requires that the current representation format, or more formally its media-type, does support dynamic content such as scripts and manipulating the current representation format.

Unfortunately, many representation formats exchanged in typical "REST APIs/services" do not support such properties. A plain JSON document i.e. just defines the basic syntax (i.e. objects are key-value containers in between curly braces, ...) but it does not define a semantics for any of the fields it might contain, it does not even know what a URI is and such. As such, JSON is not a good representation format for in a REST architecture to start with. While [HAL/JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08) or [JSON Hyper-Schema](http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-hypermedia.html) attempt to add support for links and rudimentary semantics, they yet create their own media-types and thus representation formats all along. Other JSON based media types, such as [hal-forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [halo+json (halform)](http://halform.herokuapp.com/) and [ion](https://ionspec.org/#forms), attempt to add form-support. Some of these media-type formats may allow to add restrictions to certain form-elements that automatically end up in a user warning and a block of the actual document transmission if violated, though most of the current media types might yet lack support for client-sided scripts or dynamic content updates.

Such circumstances lead Fielding in one of his [famous blog posts](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) to a statement like this:

> A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types

Usually the question should not be which media type to support but how many different ones your server/client should support as the more media type representation it may handle the more it will be able to interact with its peer. And ideally you want to reuse the same client for all interactions while the same server should be able to server a multitude of clients, especially ones not under your direct control.

In regards to a "RESTful" solution I would not recommend using custom headers or proprietary message formats as they are usually only understood and thus processable by a limited amount of clients, which is the opposite of what the REST architecture actually aims to achieve. Such messages usually also require a priori knowledge of the server behavior which may lead to problems if the server ever needs to change.

So, long story short, in essence the safest way to introduce "RESTful" (~ one that is in accordance with the constraints the REST architecture put in place) input validation to a resource is by using a form-based representation, that teaches a client on everything it needs to create an actual request, where the request is processed by the server and if certain input constraints are validated leads to returning the form to the client again with a hint on the respective input problem.

If you want to minimize the interaction between client and server due to performance considerations (which are usually not the core problem at hand) you might need to define your own media type that adds script support and dynamic content updates, through similar means such as DOM manipulation or the like. Such a custom media type however should be [registered with IANA](https://www.iana.org/form/media-types) to allow other implementors to add support for such types and thus allow other clients to interact with your system in future.